# Как решить проблему uvd not responding на kali linux

Tags: linux, xorg, amd, kali-linux

У меня Кали Линукс.  Я веб разработчик и мне нужны эти инструменты для пентестинга, которые есть на этой ОС. Но дело не только в этом. Я уже привык к нему.  Расставаться не хочется уже научился разбираться с проблемами через терминал.  Но одну проблему я никак не могу решить. При загрузке экран становится черно белым(как телевизор без антенны). Раньше я тупо набирал пароль и нажимал энтер(не видя ничего) и экран обновлялся и вуаля - десктоп открыт. Но мне пришлось перезаписать кали 64(раньше был 32). Так вот сейчас таже проблема, но ввод непомогает. Он просто зависает в этом "тв" режиме. Я читал миллионы статей. Перебирал всяческие методы. Но не помогает. Большинство советует nomodeset в грубе. Но это запускает ОС в отвратительном разрешении и с черепашьей скоростью. Дрова тоже найти невозможно. AmdCatalyst напрочь отказывается поддерживать современный xorg. А установочный iso уже идет с xorg последних версий.  Как быть? Где копать? Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Прошу не советовать то, что я уже описал.

Comment: Может так: http://archlinux.org.ru/forum/topic/14016/

Comment: @Sergey может.  Но я не понял что он сделал.